# use of "claw" in this context

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

I think the verb "claw means  to score. But why does the writer use "claw" instead of "score?" What does it suggest?

> Mohamed Salah **clawed** one back for Liverpool in the 81st minute to
> produce a nervy finish for Red Devils fans

Comment: Note the 'back'. You can claw something back, but you can't score something back.

Comment: If so, what does "claw" exactly mean in that context?

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a phrasal verb **[claw back](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/claw-back)**, which the Cambridge Dictionary defines as:

> to get possession of something again with difficulty

It's actually an incorrect usage of **claw back** since it should only really apply to regaining something that you have lost, and a goal is something that you never had in the first place.

It is often used in sports to describe regaining a favourable position- either in the course of a game (for example going from winning to losing to winning again), or a position in a league table (dropping in the table and then climbing again).

It was written by a sports commentator, so you cannot expect it to make complete sense.

Comment: Thank you. Is it common to use this phrase for sports like football?

Comment: What they had lost was either the lead (if they had been ahead earlier in the game) or the equal/drawn status they had at the start of the game.  Scoring a goal could be said to be part of "clawing back" that status, which is probably what the commentator was thinking of.

Comment: @Jembot yes, it is widely used in sports, but generally about clawing back some former position rather than clawing back a goal.